# Is there any way to save only the maximum probabilities in the softmax prediction in Keras?

Tags: keras, out-of-memory, softmax

I am using *tensorflow* and *keras* to build a Neural Network. The problem is that I have 40k categories and 1M entries for a classification problem, and when I try to predict all probabilities for each category by using a softmax, I get a memory error (I think it is because it cannot save such a large array 1M x 40k).

However, for me is enough to know, for example, the three most likely categories for each subject in my dataset. This can reduce a lot the size of the array (1M x 3). So is there any way to get only the three most likely categories in the prediction of Keras? Or I mandatorily must save all the probabilities for each category?

Thank you all!

Comment: There's no way of getting the top-3 predictions without first getting all 40k labels and manually slicing off the top 3. Are you making predictions on the entire 1m rows in one go?

Comment: @ML_Engine Well, I use a batch_generator and the predict_generator function to introduce data little by little. But it still saves all the probabilities for all rows in the final array prediction, and the prediction raises a OOM error.

Comment: Thanks for the update, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding a custom callback to your predict function. The below code
gets the predictions from each batch (from the logs that gets created automatically) and allows you to perform operations on them.

Rather than just sorting by score you'll need to get the indices of the top N scores first in order for you to be able to convert the one-hot encoding back into your original labels, however that is beyond the scope of this question. If you're using a [labelencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) you could just :

- do `inverse_transform` inside the callback to get the actual labels
- and then zip them together with the scores
- then sort by the score inside the tuple
- then extract the top N labels

Once you've found an appropriate algorithm for sorting and getting the indices or labels, you can then just extend the results to an external list (`extend` because you want to add each individual batch as a bunch of separated lists rather than just adding one extra element per batch (as would occur with `append`)) and then just join this back to your original test set.

`del logs` at the end will clear all the predictions from memory and then continue with the next batch.

```
top2_predictions=[]

class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_predict_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):

        preds = logs['outputs']

        <insert indices sorting code, maybe np.argpartition>

        top2 = preds[:, :2]

        top2_predictions.extend(top2)

        del logs


model.predict(test_dataset, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```